# Creating of the Jordan Canonical Form

Tags: matrix, expression-construction

I have a matrix polynomial P(s) and the Jordan blocks of P(s) corresponding to every eigenvalue sj (j=1,...,k).

How can the Jordan Canonical Form be generated, i.e. the block diagonal matrix which has the Jordan blocks in the diagonal elements ?

Any help would be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

If you have e.g. n=3 Jordan blocks, you may assemble the total matrix e.g. by:

```
n = 3;
bl1 = {{1, 1}, {0, 1}};
bl2 = 2;
bl3 = {{3, 1, 0}, {0, 3, 1}, {0, 0, 3}};
ArrayFlatten[
  DiagonalMatrix[Range[3]] /. 
   Thread[Range[3] -> {bl1, bl2, bl3}]] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There's an internal, undocumented function:

```
LinearAlgebra`BlockDiagonalMatrix[<list of Jordan blocks>]
```

Example:

```
ClearAll[jordanBlock];
jordanBlock[λ_, 1] := λ*IdentityMatrix[1];
jordanBlock[λ_, dim_] :=(* dim > 1 *)
  λ*IdentityMatrix[dim] + DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[1, dim - 1], 1];

SeedRandom[1];
LinearAlgebra`BlockDiagonalMatrix[
 Table[jordanBlock[RandomInteger[{-3, 3}], RandomInteger[{1, 3}]], {4}]
 ]
% // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Alternative code for `jordanBlock[λ_, dim_]`:

```
jordanBlock[λ_, dim_] :=
 SparseArray[{{i_, i_} :> λ, {i_, j_} /; j == i + 1 :> 1}, {dim, dim}]
```

Comment: Yes your way works fine, but in fact I don't want random integers. In my algorithm, I enter the matrix polynomial P and then are calculated the eigenvalues. I have an iteration for eigenvalues, where for every eigenvalue are generated the Jordan blocks. In the end, after the iteration, I want to generate the block diagonal matrix which has the Jordan blocks in the diagonal elements. How could this be done?Thank you.

Comment: @xelen Substitute a list of your Jordan blocks for my `Table[...]` -- I think that's clearly stated in my first, general solution., no?  Had you provided your list in the Q, I would have used it; instead, I had to make up my own for the sake of an example. I don't know why you think `RandomInteger` is necessary for using ``LinearAlgebra`BlockDiagonalMatrix``. Using `jordanBlock[]` is not necessary either but, again, was included for the sake of an example.